# How to get all storeIds opened 12 months before a specific date with Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to retrieve all `storeId`s where `dateOpened >=12` months before a specific date (e.g., 10/4/2017). What SQL statement can do it? The `dateOpened` field is a timestamp. I'm using Google BigQuery Legacy SQL.

Answer (score 1):

> We're using Google's BigQuery Legacy SQL.

For BigQuery Legacy SQL you can use as below

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT storeId FROM
WHERE dateOpened 
  BETWEEN DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP('2017-10-04'), -12, 'MONTH') 
  AND TIMESTAMP('2017-10-04')
```

you can test/play-with this using below "template" with dummy data

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT storeId FROM
  (SELECT 1 AS storeId, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS dateOpened), 
  (SELECT 2 AS storeId, TIMESTAMP('2017-02-10') AS dateOpened), 
  (SELECT 3 AS storeId, TIMESTAMP('2017-03-10') AS dateOpened), 
  (SELECT 4 AS storeId, TIMESTAMP('2016-03-10') AS dateOpened) 
WHERE dateOpened 
  BETWEEN DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP('2017-10-04'), -12, 'MONTH') 
  AND TIMESTAMP('2017-10-04')
```

As you might noticed - the answers you got so far are for BigQuery Standard SQL
BigQuery Team very strongly suggests using Standard SQL - if you will decide to follow - see [`Migrating to Standard SQL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql)

Comment: That works, thanks  for helpt! 
Considering migrating to StandardSQL - unfortunately, it's not me who's in position to decide on it. But if

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you can do this using dates (I don't see any reason why the time component would be important for this type of query):

```
where date(dateOpened) >= dateadd(date(2017, 10, 4), interval -12 month)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
#standardSQL
WITH data AS(
  SELECT 1 storeId, TIMESTAMP("2017-08-31") dateOpened UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP("2017-07-31") UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, TIMESTAMP("2017-05-31") UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, TIMESTAMP("2017-03-31") UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, TIMESTAMP("2017-01-31") UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, TIMESTAMP("2016-12-31") UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, TIMESTAMP("2016-09-30") UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, TIMESTAMP("2016-05-31") UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, TIMESTAMP("2016-02-28")
)

SELECT
  storeId
FROM data
WHERE DATE(dateOpened) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE("2017-08-01"), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AND DATE("2017-08-01")
```

Where `2017-08-01` is your input string used as reference in the filtering.